# Sending attachments of greater size asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, email, smtp

i have developed one windows (desktop) based application which sends pdf as an attachments. the size of pds could range from 40 KB to 10-15 MB. But when i send an pdf more than 2.5 MB the file is never reaching the destination.

I try sending the file at our intranet as well popular internet (such as gmail, yahoo) email address but no luck!

Also i cross checked in SMTP Server. No such limitations has been imposed therein.

My code is in Asp.net 2.0 and C#.

let me know if more details required.

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

> SmtpClient.Timeout value.

### the  default  value is 100 seconds = 100000.

or check out this link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1402417.aspx/1

Comment: where should i keep .timeout property? After calling send method of my smtpclient object?

Comment: I think you should read this link so you got to know that where you give the value of .timeout. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons ASP.net has a pre defined max size which is 4mb. to allow uploads you need to modify your web config. Adding the httpRuntime  setting which is to be added to the  section of your web config.

Below is an example of this which sets the upload size to be 8MB.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"/>
</system.web>
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx for more details.

Comment: i guess this tweak doesn't apply to windows based application.

Comment: no from reading your question i thought u were working with ASP.net application.